# How to add constraints programmatically in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview, constraints

I set to `myWebView` bottom constraint `74` in XCode. But in some cases I want to set it equal to `0`. For it I did:

```
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myWebView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myWebView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

myWebView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

but it doesn't work. How can I make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to tell : "I want the center of my webview to be at 0px from the center of my web view".

This is pretty much always the case I think ;).

I think the constraint you want to add must be related to the bottom of superview of the webview.

You can do as follows :

```
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myWebView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myWebView.superview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

myWebView.superview.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

Please note I add positioning constraints to the superview of the "positioned" view.